# Determine when does a spherical curve closes.

Tags: 3d, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

So I'm plotting curves in three dimensions on my computer. I'm currently using equations in spherical coordinates to define them. These are some examples, using ISO convention ( r , θ , φ ):

$\big(a.sin(b.\theta), \theta, c\big)$

$\big(a.sin(b.\theta), \theta, \theta\big)$

$\big(a.abs(sin(b.\theta)), \theta, c.sin(d.\theta)\big)$

**How could I find the closing angle for these variations?**

Maybe a good starting point should be looking at 2D rhodoneas. According to wolfram, a two-dimensional rhodonea curve ($r = a.cos(\frac{r}{s}.\theta)$) closes at a polar angle of $\theta=\pi .s.p$, where $p=1$ if $r.s$ is odd and $p=2$ if $r.s$ is even. But I can't understand why that happens.

Ref:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rose.html

I'm probably missing something or maybe I got something wrong, so if you have any thoughts on this I would love to know and discuss it further.

Comment: I'm really stuck with this issue, not sure if I'm using the right terms for the problem I'm describing. If anyone comes across this and needs me to explain it further please comment and I'll reply immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are asking for the angle at which the curves are 'back at their starting point'. Let's start with the rhodoneas. You might know that the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are periodic with a period of $2\pi$, meaning that they are back at their starting point at an angle of $2\pi$ radians.
A curve of the form $r=a\cos(\frac{n}{s} \theta)$ is back at its starting point when $\frac{n}{s} \theta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ for the first time. If $n$ is even (a multiple of 2) this happens at $\theta=s \cdot\pi$, because $s \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{n}{s} = n\pi$ and $n$ is a multiple of two.

If $n$ is not even this happens at $\theta=2s \cdot\pi$.

Back to your curves:

$(a \sin(b\theta), \theta, c)$ closes when $b\theta$ and $\theta$ are both a multiple of $2\pi$ for the first time. If $b$ is an integer this happens at $\theta=2\pi$, if $b$ is a rational number given by $b=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ integers, this happens at $\theta=q\cdot 2\pi$.

If $b$ is irrational, the curve never closes because an integer multiple of $2\pi$ cant also be an integer multiple of $2\pi \cdot b$.

Similar logic applies to the other two curves.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that $\theta$ needs to be an integer multiple of $2\pi$, otherwise the curve won't end at a point equivalent to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. Following your train of thought: When talking about curves of the form $r=a\cos(\frac{n}{s} \theta)$ wouldn't the closing angle (the very first time the curve is back at the starting point) be $\theta = \frac{2s \cdot \pi}{n}$ for all cases?

Comment: That is indeed the point at which $\cos$ is back at its starting point, not the curve however. Keep in mind that $(\theta, r)$ needs to start and end at $(0,0)$ or $(2\pi, 0)$, or $(4\pi, 0)$, etc. (Since these points are the same in polar coördinates).

Take for example $n=4$ and $s=1$. The point $(\frac{2s\pi}{n}, 0) = (\frac{1\pi}{2}, 0)$ is not equal to $(0,0)$ and therefore cannot be the closing point. See also this [interactive example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sckfyrclr3)

Comment: I was just plotting with Desmos trying to understand what you said, thank you for this perfect explanation and example.

Comment: @rumpelstiltskin Glad i could help!